# ReactJS ordered list numbering is not being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

ReactJS ordered list numbering is not being displayed.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

- I want to generate a list of questions with answers. These questions are rendered into the DOM from a JSON that my app retrieves.

Below is the code that I think is relevant:

Main entry point:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
require('./index.css');
var App = require('./components/App')

ReactDom.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

App.js

```
var React = require('react');
var QuestionList = require('./QuestionList');

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <QuestionList />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = App
```

QuestionList.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Schema = require('./Schema');
var Category = require('./Category')

class QuestionList extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 key={Schema.questionSetId}>{Schema.questionSetTitle}</h1>
                {Schema.category.map(function(obj, i) {
                    return <Category key={i} obj={obj}/>;
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = QuestionList;
```

Category.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Question = require('./Question');

class Category extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.obj.name}</h3>
                <ol type="1">
                    {this.props.obj.questions.map(function(obj, i) {
                        return <li key={i}><Question obj={obj} /></li>;
                    })}
                </ol>
            </div>
        )
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

module.exports = Category;
```

Question.js

```
var React = require('react');
var QuestionScore = require('./QuestionScore');

class Question extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.obj.questionTitle}</p>
                <QuestionScore obj={this.props.obj.questionScore} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

module.exports = Question;
```

QuestionScore.js

```
var React = require('react');

class QuestionScore extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                Score (type : {this.props.obj.type}) = {this.props.obj.score}
            </div>
        )
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

module.exports = QuestionScore;
```

I haven't included the Schema.js file (thats where my JSON is) because I don't think its relevant since I can pass the data down the chain just fine.

[This is what browser displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWtLa.png)

[This the source code that gets generated by react when I inspect it in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F82Pk.png)

I saw somewhere that there could be indentation issues, so I installed and setup eslint, but everything stayed the same. I am pretty new to ReactJS (been learning it for the past 2 weeks), so I have a hunch its a stupid mistake I am making. I would be very grateful to whomever can point it out :)

Other notes: I am coding in Visual Code and building with webpack. The ReactJS app will be displayed inside an IFrame in the DevExpress XAF framework.

EDIT 1: As James King suggested, the problem is CSS. I built this project following a tutorial and their CSS had this line:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

It never occurred to me to look there, but it seems obvious in retrospect. Once I removed it, it all worked as expected.

Comment: So whats the issue? You are getting all questions list correctly.

Comment: Where is the ordered list? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Indentation isn't relevant. Neither are those spurious ctors. What isn't happening that you think should be?

Comment: Looks fine to me. I suggest this is a CSS issue

Comment: I don't see the numbered list. That's what I meant by ordered list. Even if I use a unordered list, I don't see the 'dots' in front of those items.

Comment: Can you post your CSS? Are you using a front-end framework

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean about the ctors? Do I not need them to define the fact that my component expects 'props'? Is that implied?

Comment: ctors that do nothing aren't relevant; `Component` ctor already takes `props`.

Comment: @JamesKing I think React is the front-end framework... Did you mean CSS framework?

Comment: @JamesKing You were right about the CSS issue. Thanks a bunch! I was losing my mind looking everywhere else but there.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay good to know. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @TimA. Always inspect your elements and see what styles are being applied. Also, try to be precise when describing the problem--the list itself *was* being displayed, what was missing was the associated list *numbering*.

Comment: @DaveNewton I definitely will from now on. I just got into web development as a full time job and I am still making some stupid mistakes. You are right that the list is displayed, which I could sort of tell because there was indentation, but since no numbers appeared, that gave me the impression it wasn't.

Comment: It's a process-knowing where to look can be a challenge even for experienced developers.